# jquery slick.js slider and filtering based on data attributes

Tags: jquery, slick.js

Having some trouble getting the filtering ability of the slick slider to work on data attributes.

**html :**

```
<div id="slider2">
    <div data-test-id="1">
        <img src="test.jpg" title="test" alt="test" height="120">
    </div>
    <div data-test-id="1">
        <img src="test.jpg" title="test" alt="test" height="120">
    </div>
    <div data-test-id="5">
        <img src="test.jpg" title="test" alt="test" height="120">
    </div>
</div>
```

**js :** (after slider initialized of course)

```
$('#slider2').slick('slickFilter','[data-test-id="1"]');
```

The js to filter removes all the slides when there is clearly two of them that have `data-test-id="1"`.  If I run `$('#slider2').slick('slickUnfilter');` all slides come back as they should.

I guess I need more details on how slick is executing the filtering, but there isn't much in the doc about this.  It gives the example `$('.filtering').slick('slickFilter',':even');`, but that doesn't really help me here since I need to use data attributes.  It just says to use 'Selector or Function' when calling it and it uses jquery .filter().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working with some trial/error and some changes.

**html :**

```
<div id="slider2">
    <div class="slickSlide" data-test-id="1">
        <img src="test.jpg" title="test" alt="test" height="120">
    </div>
    <div class="slickSlide" data-test-id="1">
        <img src="test.jpg" title="test" alt="test" height="120">
    </div>
    <div class="slickSlide" data-test-id="5">
        <img src="test.jpg" title="test" alt="test" height="120">
    </div>
</div>
```

**js :**

```
$('#slider2').slick('slickFilter', function() {
    return $(this).find('.slickSlide').attr("data-test-id") == "1";
});
```

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot. One thing that threw me off was your selector. It seems that you can't filter based on the wrapper ".slick-slide" it needs to be a child of that.